# I need to pass an array of String and Any as parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I'm making a class where I need to pass a 2 positions array of string and any, because each time the function is called, the type of data can be different. For example:

```
First call, data type is of type [(Int, String)]
second call, data type is of type  [(date, String)]
third call, , data type is of type  [(custom Object, String)]
etc...
```

I'm not using the `Any` data for anything inside the function. I just need to display the `String` part and return the selected element like this:

```
return (any,String)
```

I looked into tuples and generics with no success, keep getting errors, like :
`Cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, String)' to '(Any, String)'`

Does anyone know what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: As the second value is `String`, why not swapping the values and passing an array of  dictionaries with `String` key and `Any` value (`[[String:Any]]`)?

Comment: Can you show your code? Why are you returning a tuple inside an array? You can just return the tuple like this: `func function() -> (Any,String){ 
return (3,"string")
}`

Comment: What would you do with the generic parameter? obviously, if you are aiming to send a generic parameter to it such as int or even a custom object you have to treat them in one way that comfortable to any type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have te function take a (String, Any) tuple array and return the same tuple, no need to convert anything if you are just using the String part anyway.

An example

```
typealias StringAny = (String, Any)

func test(_ data: [StringAny]) -> StringAny {
  print(data[0].0)

  return data[0]
}
```

And then I tested it successfully with

```
func main() {
  let data1: [StringAny] = [("One", 1)]
  let data2: [StringAny] = [("Today", Date())]

  if let intValue = test(data1).1 as? Int {
    print("Int is \(intValue)")
  }
  if let dateValue = test(data2).1 as? Date {
    print("Date is \(dateValue)")
  }
}

main()
```

I see now that I have swapped String and Any in the tuple compared to your example.

Here is the output when I run my example

[Running] swift "/Users/joakim/Development/test.swift"

One

Int is 1

Today

Date is 2018-02-27 16:29:00 +0000

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.455 seconds

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up just casting the data
let arrayDataSource : [(Any, String)] = [(1, "First item"),(2, "Second item")]